# Click on variation image must change the variant value in drop down shopify

Tags: image, select, shopify, variant

In shopify, I want when image is selected, its corresponding selected variant value must appear in the select box. However, vice-versa is happening i.e. when value is selected from select box, it scrolls to that image.

Here is the link:
https://www.statementoutfit.com/collections/brillen/products/steampunk-trendy-zonnebril-design-modern-double-dubbel-hip-en-eye-catching-statement?variant=18146439069793

Anyone please help me to get the desired results.

Comment: Either you have missed js for this slideshow or js for this slideshow is clashing with theme js(you can alter the positioning of js file).

Comment: There are no separate files for slideshow and theme.js. All code is in theme.js and I have tried rearranging js files. Its not working. Can someone please help.